# Date selection problem with JQuery Plugin DATE RANGE PICKER

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using the [DATE RANGE PICKER JQUERY plugin](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/date_range_picker_using_jquery_ui_16_and_jquery_ui_css_framework/) in one of my project. The datebox is rendered using this HTML code

```php
<span class="datePickUnity" id="arrowDate">
  <input type="text" name="<?php echo $name; ?>" value="<?php echo $inputValue; ?>" id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="datePickBox" />
  <div class="calendarArrowBox"><img src="<?php echo $dirIMG; ?>/arrow.png" class="calendarArrow" alt="Select Date Range" /></div>
</span>
```

I call the function this way

```
$(function(){
  $('#dateRange').daterangepicker();
});
```

then it works, it puts the value return into the #dateRange input box

But now I need it to work when I click on the whole span tag #arrowDate I do this by using this code

```
$(function(){
  $('#arrowDate').daterangepicker();
});
```

the date range picker pop's up, but whern I select my date I need it to insert the date into the #dateRange input box, is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: why dont you attach click method to your span and call $('#dateRange').daterangepicker();ž

Comment: @Senad - I did but it then does not bring up the date range selecter

Comment: @Senad I did the following $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#arrowDate').click(function() {

              $('#dateRange').daterangepicker();
                });
            });

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$(function(){
  $('#dateRange').daterangepicker();
  $('#arrowDate').click(function (e) {
    if ( !($('#dateRange').is(e.target)) )
      $('#dateRange').click();
    }
  });
});
```